# A circuit that gives momentary contact when I close a switch

Tags: switches, button

I need a circuit that gives momentary contact when I close a switch and will give another momentarily contact when I open the same switch again. So when I switch a switch on there must be a circuit that acts as a push button switch and when I switch that switch off again it must act as another separate push button. I have a device that switches on with a push button and switches off with another push button. I want to switch the device on and off with a thermostat by using a circuit that connects the thermostat to those two push buttons, so that I can still use them to switch the device if I want to.

I am running a 220 V fridge from an 1000 W 12 V / 220 V inverter. I want the inverter to switch on when the fridge thermostat switches on and switch off when the Thermostat switches off, because I do not want the inverter to draw battery current while the fridge is not running. The problem is that the inverter is not switched on by a on/off switch. You press one push button to start it and another one to stop it, so I cannot just connect the thermostat switch in parallel with a inverter switch. I have access to the inverter PC board and I can see both push buttons' contact points. So I need to connect the thermostat switch to the two push button switches through a circuit that will connect the START push button's two contact points momentarily when the thermostat switch is making contact and do the same for the STOP push button when the thermostat switch opens.

---

I came up with this circuit, I would appreciate any comments if you see mistakes.

[image: toggle to momentary]

Comment: You have told us what you want but didn't ask a question. Where are you stuck? You're looking for a "rising edge pulse generator" and a "falling edge pulse generator".

Comment: Would momentary contact switches do it for you? They sit at center and you bump them up or down for momentary on/off.  They're used with latching relays.

Comment: Any electronic solution is going to require that your first figure out how to safely simulate a button press in the target circuit, which means understanding how its button is electrically monitored.  It's possible that something like a capacitor driving the gate of an FET would do, but the challenge is in the missing details.

Comment: Transistor, Harper,Chris please see my edited question

Comment: (Q1) Will the inverter start if you hold the ON button? Will it switch of if you let go the ON button and hold the OFF button? (Q2) Do the on and off buttons share a common wire. (Q3) Does the thermostat have a changeover contact? (Q4) If not, what way is the contact when fridge temperature is below setpoint?

Comment: yes it starts if i hold, yes it switches off.No they dont share.I have not opened the fridge yet so im not sure if it has, but if it has to have one I can replace it. They usually have a changeover.When the fridge is to cold the thermostat contact is closed.

Comment: I would like to post a photo but I dont know how. I also saw a diagram for a "constant to momentary" relay. its a relay with a Capacitor, resistor and looks like a diode connected to it, could that work?

Comment: "*I would like to post a photo but I dont know how.*" Use the image upload button on the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Will the inverter start if you hold the ON button? Will it switch of if you let go the ON button and hold the OFF button? **yes it starts if i hold, yes it switches off.**.
> 2. Do the on and off buttons share a common wire. **No they dont share.**
> 3. Does the thermostat have a changeover contact? **I have not opened the fridge yet so im not sure if it has, but if it has to have one I can replace it. They usually have a changeover.**
> 4. If not, what way is the contact when fridge temperature is below setpoint? **When the fridge is to cold the thermostat contact is closed.**

If everything is as you say *and* the inverter buttons have a common wire then all you need to do is as shown in Figure 1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTNC3i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Thermostat wiring for inverter control.*

Comment: Hi Transistor. they dont share a common wire